# Flutter Android Release Build Signing Failed

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

`Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1` This is the error I am getting when I run `flutter build apk --release`

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "***"
            storeFile file("***")
            storePassword "*****"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

When I do the following it works fine.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // which is by default by flutter
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

I also tried `flutter clean`

The keystore is fine. Since, I can create apk through android studio using it.

I want to sign my apk manually, through CI/CD. It's just not working. Please someone help me out! I wasted my whole day!

Flutter Version - 1.7.8+hotfix.4
Gradle Plugin Version - 3.3.1

Comment: i had same issue . if your key file path is correct did you clean your android project?  after clean and rebuild in android project my flutter command worked.  and used these instructions https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are using Firebase then are you sure that you set up everything correctly?

Including the google-services file that you should put inside your project in order to close the apk.

Comment: I'm not using firebase. The project builds successfully through android studio.

Comment: Did you check the path of my key.properties
Maybe you used ../key.jks (relative path) instead of absolute path /Users/username/path/to/my/key/key.jks

Comment: I placed the file just next to the ```app/build.gradle```. E.g. ```app/something.jks```

and inside the gradle i did ```storeFile file("something.jks")```

Comment: Try with the absolute path instead

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution :(

Comment: Sure bro. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it somehow. I still don't know what fixed it. But, here are the things I tried. I really don't have enough time to find out the exact reason, because it consumes a lot of time to create release build.

Things did/found out.

1. Flutter gives the same error if there is any error in ur build.gradle file, if there is something incorrect in your keystore credentials, etc.
2. You cannot create a release build without signingConfig. In a regular android project you can do that. But if you don't specify signingConfig then again you get the same error. Which means, you cannot manually sign the apk? I'm not sure of this please comment if you know.